# HTML CSS JavaScript - Auto height RWD

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created sections that display poorly on mobile.
I'm looking for a way for the div height to be set automatically.

On mobile devices, when the content is longer, the elements do not keep the layout.

I was looking for Javascript code but none works.

My code:

```css
#blocks {
  width: 100%;
}

#blocks div {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  margin: 2vw 0 2vw 0;
}

#blocks div p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0 0 0 10%;
  color: black;
}

#blocks img {
  padding: 0 0 0 10%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #blocks div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 25vh;
    float: left;
  }
  #blocks div:last-child {
    margin-bottom: calc(10% + 30px);
  }
  #blocks div p {
    font-size: 3vw;
    padding: 0 10%;
  }
  #blocks img {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 10%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="blocks">
  <div class="block1">
    <img src="img/block.jpg">
    <p>Lorem ipsum<br> Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum<br> Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>

  <div class="block2">
    <img src="img/block2.jpg">
    <p>Lorem ipsum<br> Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum<br> Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum<br> Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>

  <div class="block3">
    <img src="img/block3.jpg">
    <p>Lorem ipsum<br> Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum<br> Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum<br> Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The height of the blocks is automatically the same.
How to make it automatic?

Comment: `#block` for  `id="blocks"` does not match :) Also, you should consider flex or even grid nowdays, not float

Comment: yes, typo, thank you

Comment: but the question is still valid :)

Answer (score 0):

You might laugh, at this code...

```js
let verticalCentering = function () {
    let el = document.querySelector("#yourdivnameandyourwelcome.");
    el.style.marginTop = (window.innerHeight - el.offsetHeight) / 2 + 'px';
}
verticalCentering(); // Insert this in resize events or after you've called the element!

window.onresize = () => verticalCentering();
```

CSS to my element:

```
position: absolute;
display: block;
color: white;
left: 0;
right: 0;
max-width: 50%;
min-width: 150px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 6px;
background: #101314;
border-radius: 6px;
word-break: break-word;
user-select: none;
box-shadow: #64aeed 0 0 5px 0px;
overflow: hidden;
max-height: 60%;
```

There's no way to adjust a div's height properly once the height is dynamic. So this calculates and resituates the div.

Comment: You may set min-height/max-height now for your div's and use the media property. This code will set elements height to center of the page at any height offered assuming it's not 100%+:)

Comment: Thank you. But i cant use this. not working :/

Comment: I get the struggles, this solved my issue but my CSS is a bit advanced now so may require plucking at but found the margin-top trick to find ccenter very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try flex:

```
#blocks {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The main div takes a flex argument. But how to configure it for mobile? as #blocks div?